# Sequelize nodejs : search by column from table columns and its join table columns

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js, where-clause, sql-like

I have table (`skill_plan`) which has foreign key of other table (`skill_set`). I need to filter `findAndCountAll` result by search_input if available , by some columns of `skill_plan` and some columns of `skill_set`.

I have tried below code.

```
let search_input = req.body.search_input;
  var whereStatement = {};

  if (search_input) {
    whereStatement = {
      [Op.or]: [
        {
          title: {
            [Op.like]: `%${search_input}%`,
          },
        },
        {
          year: {
            [Op.like]: `%${search_input}%`,
          },
        },
        {
          quarter: {
            [Op.like]: `%${search_input}%`,
          },
        },
      ],
    };
  }

  await SkillPlan.findAndCountAll({
    include: [
      {
        model: SkillSet,
        required: true,
        attributes: ["id", "skill_name", "status"],
        where: search_input
          ? {
              [Op.or]: [
                {
                  skill_name: {
                    [Op.like]: `%${search_input}%`,
                  },
                },
              ],
            }
          : null,
      },
    ],
    where: whereStatement,
    distinct: true,
  })
```

Above code executing query like below

```
SELECT
   count(DISTINCT(`skill_plan`.`id`)) AS `count` 
FROM
   `skill_plan` AS `skill_plan` 
   INNER JOIN
      `skill_sets` AS `skill_set` 
      ON `skill_plan`.`skill_set_id` = `skill_set`.`id` 
      AND 
      (
         `skill_set`.`deleted_at` IS NULL 
         AND 
         (
            `skill_set`.`skill_name` LIKE '%test%'
         )
      )
WHERE
   (
      `skill_plan`.`deleted_at` IS NULL 
      AND 
      (
         `skill_plan`.`title` LIKE '%test%' 
         OR `skill_plan`.`year` LIKE '%test%' 
         OR `skill_plan`.`quarter` LIKE '%test%'
      )
   )
;
```

But I need  `skill_set.skill_name LIKE '%test%'` condition with OR of `skill_plan` conditions.

How I can get OR of `skill_set` column in OR conditions of `skill_plan`? is there any other way of doing this?

Please guide and help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to move `SkillSet` conditions to the `SkillPlan` conditions level:

```js
if (search_input) {
    whereStatement = {
      [Op.or]: [
        {
          title: {
            [Op.like]: `%${search_input}%`,
          },
        },
        {
          year: {
            [Op.like]: `%${search_input}%`,
          },
        },
        {
          quarter: {
            [Op.like]: `%${search_input}%`,
          },
        },
        {
          '$SkillSet.skill_name$': {
            [Op.like]: `%${search_input}%`,
          },
        }
      ],
    };
  }
```

Comment: it shows error like ` "message": "Unknown column 'skill_plan.SkillSet.skill_name' in 'where clause'"`

Comment: My bad, I forgot to wrap with `$`. See the edited answer

Comment: still facing same issue

Comment: The same error or a little different?